# Getting frequency count of first item of a value in dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator, key, frequency

I have a dictionary consisting of key: value(list). I would like to do a frequency count of the first element in the list inside the dictionary.

An example of how the dictionary looks like:

```
dict_id = {'id_111': ['10'], 'id_222': ['10', '10'], 'id_234': ['9'], 'id_654': ['13', '10'], ..}
```

Desired results:

```
[(['10'], 2), (['9'], 1), (['13'], 1), ...]
```

This is what I have tried but it's using the entire list as key instead of the first element in the list.

```
newDict = [(k, len(list(v))) for k, v in itertools.groupby(ids.values())]
print newDict

>> [(['10'], 1), (['10', '10'], 1), (['13', '10'], 1), ...]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newDict = {}
for k, v in dict_id.iteritems():
    if v[0] in newDict:
        newDict[v[0]] += 1
    else:
        newDict[v[0]] = 1
print newDict
```

This will create an actual dictionary though.

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import Counter
print Counter(dict_id[k][0] for k in dict_id)
# Counter({'10': 2, '9': 1, '13': 1})
```

If you want the output to be in the format you specified in the question

```
print [([k], c) for k, c in Counter(dict_id[k][0] for k in dict_id).items()]
# [(['9'], 1), (['10'], 2), (['13'], 1)]
```

Comment: Just love those `Counter` questions :P

Comment: >>> dict_id = {'id_111': ['10'], 'id_222': ['10', '10'], 'id_234': ['9'], 'id_654': ['13', '10'],'id_333': ['10', '7']}
>>> print Counter(dict_id[k][0] for k in dict_id)
Counter({'10': 3, '9': 1, '13': 1})
Sir you are only checking for [k][0]. Not working in this condition.

Comment: @TanveerAlam I believe that is what the OP is looking for :)